# The need to encode or encrypt an email address in a cookie

Tags: php, cookies, encryption, encoding

Somewhere, but I can't remember where, I read that when storing sensitive information in cookies, you should encrypt or at least encode the data.

I'm only using one cookie so far and its only for a remember my email feature on the login page.  Encrypting seems to be a bit overkill but I was wondering if its good practice to at least encode an email address stored in a cookie?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Why store the email address in a cookie: if you're using it as a login name, then store it in session.... or store a unique numeric ID for each user record instead

Comment: @MarkBaker I'm not storing it to be used as user authentication, only to be a convenience to the user so they don't have to re-enter their email address when they want to login.

Comment: Give them a unique value to store in the cookie that can then be linked in your database to their user record, and hence to their email... then you don't need to store the email address in a cookie... when you build the login page, you can access the db using the unique cookie value to retrieve their email and prepopulate the login name

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks for the idea, I hadn't thought about doing it that way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer: **It doesn't hurt**

Honestly, if they are putting their email into a web form, I wouldn't care too much to encrypt it.  I would probably base64 encode it, more or less so I don't have to worry about unicode characters.  But full-out encrypt it?  Probably not necessary for the average website.

But, like I said, it doesn't hurt. Although I don't think it's necessary, if you are uncomfortable leaving people's email in the cookie, a simple [crypt](https://www.php.net/crypt) call can give you some peace of mind.

Any type of session hijacking cannot be done by email address alone, but it *is* a privacy concern to have someone be able to associate their email with your website.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I'm not too worried about it and I'm probably going to go with a simple base64_encode for the email address.

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/34955/should-cookies-that-contain-non-sensitive-information-be-encrypted This gives a better perspective. Encrypt the channel ! a hijacker and replay an encrypted cookie too

Answer (score 1):

Its a better user privacy protection policy to encrypt its data. So I think you should encrypt the user email.

Read [this](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/encrypting-cookies-in-the-browser) article, as it might help you a little bit